# How to deal with second hand reference data in event driven architectures?

Tags: domain-driven-design, microservices, eventual-consistency

What is the best way of dealing with secondary reference data in event driven architectures?

For example, if you have an event from an "*Employee*" domain that includes some reference data from the "*Organisation Structure*" domain (like name of the division they work for etc,) - do you add that secondary reference data to the event or do you add a change feed to the *Organisation Structure* domain such that the reference data comes together in your service and join it on the foreign key passed in the event?

(Or do you fall back on synchronous request response to populate the secondary reference data when you receive the event from the "Employee" domain)?

Answer (score 1):

The most common answer is to treat your reference data like any other input data - if you need that data to correctly interpret the history, then you copy that reference data into this history.

What you can sometimes do is copy into your history a key that can be used to look up an *immutable* copy of the reference data.  (Think "commit id" from git == not the data itself, but something precisely specific to the values of the data.)

You are making trade offs here -- your ability to consume that history is going to depend on the availability of the reference data, and your own history is clearly more available than a view of reference data that is "somewhere else".

For reference data that changes slowly and on a schedule, it can make sense to build that reference data into your libraries, so that it is "always" available when processing histories.  An example of this would be something like an issue of [UN/LOCODE](https://www.unece.org/cefact/locode/welcome.html); the data changes only a couple times a year, most of the entries are not changed, and so on.  Under those conditions, you can (probably) copy only the identifier into your history, and use that identifier to reliably look up the rest of the data as you need it.